# Is there a Python convention to avoid long lines of code?

Tags: python

Should I create variables just to avoid having long lines of code?  For example, in the code below the variable `stream_records` is only used once after it's set.

```
stream_records = stream.get_latest_records( num_records_to_correlate ).values('value')
stream_values = [float(record['value']) for record in stream_records]
```

Should I have done this instead?

```
stream_values = [float(record['value']) for record in stream.get_latest_records( num_records_to_correlate ).values('value')]
```

I am trying to optimize for readability. I'd love some opinions on whether it's harder to have to remember lots of variable names or harder to read long lines of code.

EDIT:

Another interesting option to consider for readability (thanks to John Smith Optional):

```
stream_values = [
    float(record['value'])
    for record in stream.get_latest_records(
        num_records_to_correlate
    ).values('value')
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) is the style guideline from the beginning of Python, and it recommends that no source lines be longer than 79 characters.

Using a variable for intermediate results also performs a kind of documentation, if you do your variable naming well.

Answer (score 3):

Newlines (carriage return) inside parentheses count as blank.
The same applies to newlines inside brackets, as pointed out by Bas Swinckels.
So you could do something like that:

```
stream_values = [
    float(record['value'])
     for record in stream.get_latest_records(
        num_records_to_correlate
     ).values('value')
]
```

You can also use `\` to continue a statement on the following line.
For example:

```
long_variable_name = object1.attribute1.method1(arg1, arg2, arg3) + \
 object2.attribute2.method2(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: In this case, the \ is not needed, since everything within the brackets is automatically interpreted as a single line.

Comment: For reference: [implicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining) ...

Comment: Oh, yes, I often do that. But the `for` as the first word on a line looked strange (looks like a `for` loop). That's why I felt like putting a \ on the preceding line. You're right of course. It was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

the first one is definitely easier to read so if there are no performance concerns I would totally go for more variables as long as they have self-explanatory names. it's also way easier to debug if somebody (not you) has to.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is indeed more readable. Creating a variable doesn't cost you a lot here, so you can leave your code with it. Plus, if you are debugging it, it will be much easier to see if the error comes from the call of `get_latests_records` or from your list comprehension.

However, another way nice way would be to construct your list with the `map` function:

```
stream_values = map(lambda x: float(x['value']), 
                    stream.get_latest_records(num_records_to_correlate) \
                    .values('value')])
```

The `lambda` here is necessary, to apply `float` on the correct value of the dictionary. As you can see, I have limited the number of chars per line to respect the [PEP8 convention](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which can help to make the code readable too.

Comment: I personally find the list comprehension more readable than a combination of `map` and a `lambda` function. They can also be split over multiple lines in the same way.

Comment: I think it is a point of view after all. I am pretty familiar with the `map` function so... :)